# can i use Inline expressions in my aql for a filter condition

Tags: expression, inline, arangodb

Can I use inline expressions in my aql for a filter condition like this:

```
for u in folders filter u.gacl[* filter contains(CURRENT.permissions,'c') and CURRENT.principal == 'users/12345'] return u
```

Sample data:

```
my sample data is:
 {
  "_key": "key-002",
  "_id": "folders/key-002",
  "_rev": "_YDQN32G--_",
  "guser": "users/12345",
  "code": "key-001",
  "gacl": [
    {
      "principal": "users/12345",
      "permissions": "rwd",
      "flags": "",
      "type": "A"
    }
  ],
  "isRoot": true,
  "gtime": "1527675486269",
  "gstatus": 0,
  "name": "f1",
  "guid": "key-001",
  "bosclass": "folders"
}
```

I tried, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you expect this query to return no matching documents, but it still does return the document, even though the "permissions" value does not match the expectation.

This is explained by the query's FILTER expression:

```
u.gacl[* filter contains(CURRENT.permissions,'c') and CURRENT.principal == 'users/12345']
```

This expression uses the star operator, which always produces an array as its result. As no array elements match the filter used on the individual elements, the result of the overall expression is just the empty array:

```
[]
```

So the query's FILTER condition translates to

```
FILTER []
```

And `[]` is `true` when converted to a boolean.filter(

So using this FILTER condition, every document will match.

Changing the condition to

```
FILTER LENGTH(u.gacl[* filter contains(CURRENT.permissions,'c') and CURRENT.principal == 'users/12345']) > 0
```

should do what you want.